# What are these numbers following the width?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been breaking down Twitter Bootstap and was wondering what the relation is between the 290 : 330.

I know that 330 is the number of pixels scrolled when the sidebar becomes fixed. Thanks!

```
// side bar
$('.bs-docs-sidenav').affix({
  offset: {
    top: function () { return $window.width() <= 980 ? 290 : 330 }
  , bottom: 270
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means if `$window.width()` is less than or equal to 980 then (`?`) use top offset of 290, else (`:`) use top offset of 330.

The same thing could have been written as:

```
top: function () { 
    if ($window.width() <= 980) {
        return 290;
    } else {
        return 330;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect - any idea what the bottom is?

Comment: I haven't used `affix`, and I was unable to find bottom property/method in the source code over at GitHub (https://github.com/traversal/affix-for-jquery). Sorry that I cannot help you more with it. You should probably ask a new question regarding affix bottom property.

Answer (score 2):

```
return $window.width() <= 980 ? 290 : 330
```

Use the **ternary operator** that is part of the syntax for a basic conditional expression.

what it does is, if the width is less than 980 it returns the 290 else it returns the 330.

```
variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Please refer the example below.

```
opening_time = (day == WEEKEND) ? 12 : 9; // using ternary operator
```

instead above line you can use

```
   //using normal coding 
    if (day == WEEKEND)
        opening_time = 12;
    else
        opening_time = 9;
```

Hope this will help you out. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that is a if condition

if your `window width is <= 980` it will `return 290 else 330`